# How do I install llvm-3.4 on Ubuntu 17.04 (x86_64)?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Trying to install llvm-3.4 on Ubuntu 17.04 results in:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package llvm-3.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'llvm-3.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'llvm-3.4'
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can't install `llvm-3.4` on Ubuntu 16.04, the only available versions are `llvm-3.5` and up. Since you are using Ubuntu 17.04, install `llvm-3.5` by :

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.5`

Answer (score 0):

At this post date the last version of llvm it is 4, it is much better to use:

```
   sudo apt-get install llvm
```

At least in Ubuntu 17.04, this select the last version at the moment of installatio