# LLVM version is 8 despite 10 being installed

Tags: software-installation

I have the following problem: I want to install a python package that depends on LLVM, version 9 or 10 needed to be precise. I wasn't able to do it and after browsing the site I found [this very relevant question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286131/how-do-i-install-llvm-10-on-ubuntu-18-04). Unfortunately, the answer doesn't work for me. To give more info, originally the installation command was unable to locate any package. So, I went to llvm's webpage and downloaded the installation script. After running it with version number = 10, I run again the first command of the linked question to install the dependencies. All good. Then checked the version of llvm and found it 8.0svn. So, I used the second part of the answer. The version is still 8.0svn and I 'm clueless. Thanks.

EDIT: OS version is 18.04 LTS

Comment: We have little to work with, for starters the first thing I'd need to know is what OS & especially release you are using. It's is if you document your issue, how do you start it, what do you get with `whereis` etc or other commands you used to explore your system with this issue etc.

Comment: @guiverc My release is exactly the same as in the linked question: 18.04 LTS, that's why I said it's very relevant. whereis llvm gives /usr/include/llvm but whereis llvm-10 gives /usr/include/llvm-10 and /usr/lib/llvm-10. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please add additional details to your question (greater formatting is available there allowing it to be more readable). It's safest if we're told things and not expected to make assumptions (*assumptions can lead to more problems, so be specific rather than hope we can read minds*..)

Comment: Tell me what else you need and I will add it. @guiverc